# Вывод значения атрибута на главной сайта woocommerce

Tags: javascript, php, woocommerce

Здраствуйте, пытаюсь вывести все значения атрибута на главной странице. В идеале чтобы это было в инпуте и когда пользователь вводит начало значение его дополняло варианты как в админ панели. Я так понимаю это обычная задача но найти какого-то нормального объяснения как это реализовать не удалось. Максимум чего добился это отражение на странице продукта значение атрибута
вот таким кодом

```
 <?php
    $fabric_values = get_the_terms( $product->id, 'pa_tire-season');
    foreach ( $fabric_values as $fabric_value ) {
          echo $fabric_value->name;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Вариант 1. [<select>](http://htmlbook.ru/html/select). Вариант 2. [jQuery autocomplette](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/). Вариант 3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35686707/woocommerce-auto-complete-paid-orders

Comment: да это понятно что такое селект и т.д. здесь вопрос каким образом мне обратиться к woocommerce чтобы получить список значений того или иного атрибута выходя за рамки товара (например вставить в форму что поиск по таким то значениях)

Comment: Тогда обновите свой вопрос таким образом, чтобы он однозначно идентифицировал Ваши чаянья от его решения. А то в текущей редакции он представляет шибко широкое поле для догадок "что имеется в виду".